# How to create own custom block template in cs cart

Tags: cs-cart

I am new to cs cart so I need cs cart community's help.
I need to understand how cs cart existing blocks (eg: product showcase block) are working and need to create custom cs cart reusable block.

Points which are not clear :
1.) what controller or PHP code we'll create.
2.) Controller or PHP code will call to which tpl.Simply how to pass php data to block tpl.
3.) At minimum How many files do we need and what will be there location.

So to sum up I need to develop a custom reusable cs cart block in which I can create logic in php code and design in tpl.

All type of suggestions will be appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the knowledge base articles on creating addons?  If not, that's a good place to start.  It will also help with use of terminology.  A "block" in cs-cart has a very specific meaning and is a template that can be incorporated into the block manager.

I think what you're looking for is the overall structure of an addon (I.e. a controller).

Too much to articulate here overall, but if you go to the forums and search for a title with 'tutorial' you may find some old articles that I wrote a long time ago showing how to develop an addon.  It defines the structure there as well.